# Find the path to a file in an unknown directory

Tags: python

I have a python file to print the full path of another file that can be in one of some other directories. My folder structure is given below:

```
D:\Main\Script\Myscript.py
D:\Main\Target\A\cow.txt
D:\Main\Target\B\dog.txt,p1.txt
D:\Main\Target\c\cat.txt
D:\Main\Target\D\Q1.txt
```

When I give the filename, I want to print the fullpath of that file. For example if I give "Q1.txt" it should print `D:\Main\Target\D\Q1.txt`. I tried the following, let my input file be `Myfile1`.

```
Scriptloc=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__))
if (os.path.exist(Scriptloc+".."+os.sep+".."+os.sep+A+Myfile1)):
   print "Filepath is "+Scriptloc+".."+os.sep+".."+os.sep+A+Myfile1
elif (os.path.exist(Scriptloc+".."+os.sep+".."+os.sep+A+Myfile1)):
   print "Filepath is "+Scriptloc+".."+os.sep+".."+os.sep+B+Myfile1
elif (os.path.exist(Scriptloc+".."+os.sep+".."+os.sep+C+Myfile1)):
   print "Filepath is "+Scriptloc+".."+os.sep+".."+os.sep+C+Myfile1
elif (os.path.exist(Scriptloc+".."+os.sep+".."+os.sep+D+Myfile1)):
   print "Filepath is "+Scriptloc+".."+os.sep+".."+os.sep+C+Myfile1
else:
   print "File not found"
```

Is there any other easy way to do this?

Comment: What if there are few files named `Q1.txt`?

Comment: '..\' will give the parent directory

Comment: yes it is working,but i need a better solution.So i asked.is there any other way?

Comment: @bereal - then find all the `Q1.txt` you are looking for, of course.

Comment: Useful: `glob.glob()`

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk), for example:

```
def find_file(basedir, filename):
    for dirname, dirs, files in os.walk(basedir):
        if filename in files:
            yield os.path.join(dirname, filename)

for found in find_file(basedir, 'Q1.txt'):
    print found
```

That way you don't have to hardcode your folder structure.

Answer (score 2):

you could use `pox`, which is built to navigate directories and work with filesystem manipulation

```
>>> from pox.shutils import find
>>> find('Q1.txt')
['/Users/mmckerns/Main/Target/D/Q1.txt']
```

The above can be run from any directory, and you can specify a directory root to start from.  It will find all files names `Q1.txt`, and return their full paths.  There are options to search for directories, and to ignore soft links, and all sorts of other stuff.  The search is a fast search, much like unix's `find` function.  Failing, `pox.shutils.find` will failover to python's `os.walk` (much slower)… which is what you could use if you wanted to stay within the standard library for whatever reason.

get `pox` here: https://github.com/uqfoundation